# How to deploy Titanium app on a real Android device?

Tags: android, eclipse, titanium

I would like to know how to deploy from TitaniumStudio to a real Android device. I have a titanium app that works in the emulator. But I'm clueless how to get it running on the real device.

I know how to deploy my titanium app onto my iPhone using Xcode.

I have installed Eclipse too, and has managed to deploy a simple HelloWorld.app to real Android device with it.

---

**Update**: I have just learned that deploy can be accomplished using the commandline.

```
[ 12:49:59 ~ ] $ adb install /Users/johndoe/git/helloworld/build/android/bin/app.apk
772 KB/s (2035982 bytes in 2.573s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/app.apk
Success
[ 12:50:54 ~ ] $
```

---

**Is there a way to deploy within TitaniumStudio?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There should be an "Install to Android Device" menu when you right-click on the project in App Explorer or Project Explorer view.  There is also a [image: run] icon in App Explorer toolbar that has the "Android Device" option.  You could also see the [Getting Started with Titanium Studio](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Getting+Started+with+Titanium+Studio) guide.

Answer (score 7):

From the [Titanium Studio Guide](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Deploying+to+Android+devices):

1. Configure your Android device:

   - Settings > Applications > Check 'Unknown sources'
   - Settings > Applications > Development > Check 'USB Debugging'
   - Settings > Applications > Development > Check 'Stay Awake'
2. Connect your Android Phone to your PC iwth a USB cable
3. Open your project in Titanium Studio:

   - Run Menu in App Explorer Bar > Android Device

Wait for the app to load and look for your app on the app drawer on your device, then tap the app to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Get [Titanium Mobile](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/) and you can send directly to your Android device

Comment: I can't find the download button for Titanium Mobile. I have an account on the titanium site and even when logged in there is no download button. How did you install it?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Titanium Studio its very user friendly.You can run your application on device by click on the Option "Run with Device", When you get right click on your project.

Answer (score 0):

...or choose **Install to Android Device...**

- when your Mobile is successfully USBconnected to your Computer
- when you rightclick on your project (as already mentioned by the fellows)